# SASS is not working properly. Trying to set prefixes for values of css property

Tags: css, whitespace, sass, prefix

Geez,
I tried this

```
@mixin prefix($property, $value){

    #{$property}: -webkit-#{$value};
    #{$property}:  -moz-#{$value};
    #{$property}: #{$value};
}
```

but i got this when used this `@include prefix(display, border-box)`

```
  display: -webkit- border-box;
  display: -moz- border-box;
  display: border-box;
```

There is annoying space between prefix and css value. How to get rid of it?
Thnx in advance!

Comment: u used suffix one time and prefix the other :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your code and *just swapping suffix to prefix* works fine for me.  This is the text string that I stuck into the [Sass Try Online generator](http://sass-lang.com/try.html).

```
@mixin prefix($property, $value){

    #{$property}: -webkit-#{$value};
    #{$property}:  -moz-#{$value};
    #{$property}: #{$value};
}

h2 {
    @include prefix(display, border-box)
}
```

The output looked like the following code:

```
h2 {
  display: -webkit-border-box;
  display: -moz-border-box;
  display: border-box; }
```

Comment: For some reason, the white-space disappeared and it's working fine, right now! May be I did something wrong there...

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. Code pasted into the online generator gives me no spaces, but compiled on my machine has whitespace around the '/'.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@include prefix(display,border-box); //Note there is no white space before border-box argument
```

In Sass reference:

> CSS specifies two kinds of strings: those with quotes, such as "Lucida Grande" or 'http://sass-lang.com', and those without quotes, such as sans-serif or bold. SassScript recognizes both kinds, and in general if one kind of string is used in the Sass document, that kind of string will be used in the resulting CSS.

Sass is taking that white space you wrote before your argument. Following should work, too:

```
@include prefix(display, "border-box");
```